# Как не "выгореть" при изучении языков программирования?

Tags: python

Изучаю я.п. python. Подскажите пожалуйста как не "выгореть" на  стадии обучения языкам программирования? Поделитесь личными рецептами успеха пожалуйста.
Я взял курсы от skill_box, первую неделю учился каждый день по нескольку часов до или после работы, вторая неделя уже 3 дня по часу, на 4 неделе всего 2 дня но по 2 часа занимался, сейчас не могу себя заставить вернуться к курсу, хотя мне очень интересно программирование ещё со школы и мне по прежнему нравится это занятие. Подскажите, кто как боролся с этим явлением и как победил?
Заказал так же книгу "Начинаем программировать на Python. 5-е изд." Гэддис Тони. Посоветуйте что ещё почитать ?
Заранее очень признателен!

Comment: Программирование де-факто подразумевает постоянную учёбу. Если у Вас возникают такие проблемы на первоначальном этапе, то стоит подумать о том, как это будет выглядеть в дальнейшем.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Заведи **блокнот\дневник** и записывай туда то, что изучил и своё мнение об этом. Программирование это практический навык и на теории далеко не уйдёшь поэтому обязательно практикуйся. Найди редактор кода в котором тебе будет комфортно работать.
Советую использовать **метод помодора**: 25 минут работаешь и 5 минут отдыха. Есть несколько приложений для этого. Как пример на винде в microsoft store бесплатное приложение **Focus To-Do**. Там как раз таки и сможешь записывать свои задачи.
Не стоит забывать, что у каждого свой темп изучения того или иного материала поэтому не надо себя заставлять работать когда не хочешь. Найди свой темп работы.